# Generate values based on timestamp grouping in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Have a Pandas dataframe like that:

[image]

We have timestamps (`time` column) and 4 different parts of machines in `type` column: part_1, part_2, part_3, part_4 and the column of activation which only have value `1` in it (that it was activated). I would like to add the rest classes to every timestamp and put 0 in `activated` column for them just like that:

[image]

I assume that some group-by approach with list should be used but I don't know the approach how to do that. Is that possible to do in Pandas?

Comment: Can you supply an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your problem?

Comment: [How to sort by timestamps in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462935/how-to-sort-by-timestamps-in-pandas)

Comment: I guess pd.melt() function would be helpful here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `unstack` and `stack`

```
df.set_index(['time','type']).activation.unstack(fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()
```

Or using `pivot` with `melt`

```
df.pivot(*df.columns).stack(dropna=False).fillna(0).reset_index()
```