# Regarding Pandas aggregator operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The aim of my program is to compile the max, average and min values of the sensors associated in 'datatype' on a minute basis. Refer the image

[Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW3tB.png)

I had used the below command

```
A=df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='T'), 'datatype','deviceid'])
    .agg(maximum=('value','max'),minimum=('value','min'),average=('value','mean'))
```

and obtained the below output

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0MUP.png)

I wanted to know if the timestamp can be obtained as a line item for all the datatype, currently available only for "HeartRate". What modifications do I need to make in the command?

Comment: Please don't post images. Paste as text so that other people can copy and reproduce.

Comment: it's just showing the output as grouped, so try reset_index()

Comment: where should i type reset_index()?

Comment: check this might help you :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462935/how-to-sort-by-timestamps-in-pandas

Comment: @JonathanLeon Could you inform the syntax on where to type reset_index(). I am new to pandas.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
A=df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='T'), 'datatype','deviceid'])
    .agg(maximum=('value','max'),minimum=('value','min'),average=('value','mean')).reset_index()
```